# Clear Cookies from webpages embedded through <object> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have used object tags to embed several pages of a single domain in my web page,

Example:

- example.com/en-UK
- example.com/en-US

And so on, each representing a individual country.

The problem is that the domain (example.com) uses cookies to store data such as country name and currency when a page is loaded. So when I load several pages simultaneously using object tags they all show the same country name and currency. This is not the case when the pages are loaded individually in a browser (only one page at a time).

Hence I tried to delete all cookies from example.com but I found that it is not possible to delete a cookie from a different domain. Is there any property for `<object>` tags like sandbox for Iframes to restrict them. Any other ideas to this scenario is also appreciated.

Below is the code for the object tags i use:

```
<div class='scroll-container'>
    <object class="my-object" data="https://example.com/en-UK/"></object>
    <div class='preventScroll'></div>
</div>
<div class='scroll-container'>
     <object class="my-object" data="https://example.com/en-US/"></object>
     <div class='preventScroll'></div>
</div>
```